# Visual Studio 2017 - Web Deploy - connection string problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

My issue with Web Deploy that a connection string formatted as follow in the setting:

```
metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\MSSQLSERVER2012;initial catalog=myDataBase;persist security info=True;user id=myUser;password=myPassoword;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;
```

Is somehow not considered and not sent to the web, and the deploy use the local connection string instead... that are almost same except server name...

Note: when Deploy a connection string that like this, its working normally and the web.config is correctly Deployed :

```
data source=.\MSSQLSERVER2012;initial catalog=myDataBase;persist security info=True;user id=myUser;password=myPassoword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework
```

I suspect that the syntax starting with `metadata=res:` is not accepted on Web Deploy, but I don't know how to solve it, thank you.

[image]

**Edit:**
I found that the file used to change web.config is `CSAutoParameterize.parameters.xml` I edited it, that's works, but back to same issue after rebuild... maybe is a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found where the problem come from...

The Web Deploy save his setting on a file with extension `.pubxml` his name is same as the name that you give to your web deploy profile, located in `\My Project\PublishProfiles\`

When you past in the setting dialog a connection string that contain some " the saved connection string became different, i don't know why ... So I just modify manually this file with correct value, I just have to keep in mind to modify it again if I change my Publish setting, but actually is not something that you change often.